# Interactive programming language minimizing reevaluations

Tags: programming-languages

I'm looking for any programming language, DSL, library or pattern for **live scripting** but minimizing the expressions reevaluation.

Topological sorting provides non-revaluation of expressions.

Memoization provides a simple way of not re-evaluating but is a waste of memory.

A form of topological ordering can be achieved by maintaining (in each language object) a version number for each dependency but it does not seem to be easily composable/scriptable.

Which available tools would be the most suitable?

Thank you!

(I think the closest I've found might be https://www.shinoe.org/cameleon)

Answer (score 3):

The specific *CS* topic resolving the question is:

[Incremental computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_computing)

A detailed article explaining a related DSL is:

[IceDust: Incremental and Eventual Computation of Derived Values in Persistent Object Graphs](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2016/6105/pdf/LIPIcs-ECOOP-2016-11.pdf)